# Why are my Y values much higher than 100% even though my highest value is 63%

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, yaxis

I'm trying to plot a graph using ggplot2 builder. My graph has species (Sp.) for X and percentage (Cover) for Y, with Gradient as groups and Sites as facet. However, my graph is giving me a value of 400 on the Y axis.

This is my df structure:

```
> data.frame':  720 obs. of  6 variables:
> Site    : Factor w/ 2 levels "DRP","PSP": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
> Plot_ID : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
> Gradient: Factor w/ 3 levels "Low","Medium",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
> Sp.     : Factor w/ 4 levels "AG","FA","SN",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
> P.A     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> Cover   : int  16 36 16 36 36 63 16 36 36 36 ...
```

This is my df table:

```
Site Plot_ID Gradient Sp. P.A Cover G2 Percentage
> 1  PSP       1     High  FA   1    16  3       0.16
> 2  PSP       2     High  FA   1    36  3       0.36
> 3  PSP       3     High  FA   1    16  3       0.16
> 4  PSP       4     High  FA   1    36  3       0.36
> 5  PSP       5     High  FA   1    36  3       0.36
> 6  PSP       6     High  FA   1    63  3       0.63
```

Sample of dataset:

```
Site    Plot_ID Gradient    Sp. P/A Cover
PSP 1   High    FA  1   16
DRP 1   Medium  FA  0   0
PSP 1   High    AG  1   16
DRP 1   Medium  AG  0   0
PSP 1   High    SS  0   0
DRP 1   Medium  SS  0   0
PSP 1   High    SN  1   16
DRP 1   Medium  SN  0   0
PSP 2   High    FA  1   36
DRP 2   Medium  FA  0   0
PSP 2   High    AG  0   0
DRP 2   Medium  AG  1   3
PSP 2   High    SS  0   0
DRP 2   Medium  SS  0   0
PSP 2   High    SN  0   0
DRP 2   Medium  SN  0   0
PSP 3   High    FA  1   16
DRP 3   High    FA  1   1
PSP 3   High    AG  1   16
DRP 3   High    AG  1   36
PSP 3   High    SS  0   0
DRP 3   High    SS  0   0
PSP 3   High    SN  0   0
DRP 3   High    SN  0   0
PSP 4   High    FA  1   36
DRP 4   High    FA  1   16
PSP 4   High    AG  0   0
DRP 4   High    AG  1   1
PSP 4   High    SS  0   0
DRP 4   High    SS  1   16
PSP 4   High    SN  0   0
DRP 4   High    SN  1   16
PSP 5   High    FA  1   36
DRP 5   Medium  FA  0   0
PSP 5   High    AG  0   0
DRP 5   Medium  AG  0   0
PSP 5   High    SS  0   0
DRP 5   Medium  SS  0   0
PSP 5   High    SN  0   0
```

This is the code ggplot gave me:

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(
    x = Sp.,
    fill = Gradient,
    group = Gradient,
    weight = Cover
  ) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys", direction = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(Site))
```

This is the result graph. As you can see Y axis is showing 400, but my highest % cover is 63%.

[image: grob]

It doesn't make sense to me to have 400 for Y. As can be seen in the table header I try to divide the % cover by 100 (as was suggested in a different post), but the only thing that changed was that instead of 400 the Y axis higher level was 4.

I'd also like to have error bars in the graph.

Comment: What does the y axis label say?

Comment: A `geom_bar` will give you the count, i.e. the number of observations. And with `weight=Cover` each obs. gets weighted by the value of `Cover`, e.g. for the six obs. in your example data you will get a bar with a height of 2 * 16 + 3 * 36 + 63 = 203.

Comment: 1) Can you make your example reproducible, e.g. by supplying some example data using `dput`? 2) These are counts, not estimates, so what would these error bars be displaying? 3) You are not plotting the `Percentage` column, you are just plotting the counts of the observations.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `ggplot(df, aes(Sp., Percentage, fill = Gradient)) + stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'bar') + stat_summary(fun.data = 'mean.cl.boot', geom = 'errorbar')`

Comment: @Axeman  I've added a little sample above (not the best but it is what I could manage). What I would like to plot is the % cover of each species with gradient as groups, and site as facets. So I can see the difference in percent cover by species in each gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, where you are plotting the mean +- CI for each category.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Sp., Cover, fill = factor(Gradient))) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'bar', position = 'dodge') + 
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = 'mean_cl_boot', geom = 'errorbar', 
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.2
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Almost. P/A is the presence/absence (0,1) data for each species. What I'd like to plot is the % cover which is the last column..

Comment: ok just replace `\`P/A\`` with `Cover` then..

Comment: I've tried that, however it still gives me weird Y values.

Comment: Saying that they are weird is not helpful to me. Can you at least try to explain what is different from what you are expecting? See edit for plot with `Cover`.

Comment: I don't know how to post a picture of the plot. But basically its is giving me Y values from 0-12 which I have no idea how to interpret.

Comment: As the average % cover across the observations in that category? (I can see the plot in your deleted answer, but you can also edit your question.) Again, what are you expecting??

Comment: I was just having a hard time interpreting the numbers, but I went back to the dataset and figure d it out.  One more thing is there a way to have Site as facets? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You already know how to add the facets, it's in the code of your question.